# Make google-sheet chart legand be filterable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I have problem with my chart on google sheet maybe someone can help,

I want to make the legend reactive, for example I have in a legend 7 different color of graphs I want to make it filtered which means only the color I clicked will be seen

Comment: most likely not possible

Comment: Are you sure? so it's not possible to make the chart customizable ? only the whole data or one by one ?

Comment: Show us your code and data. Perhaps we can help.